# Clear interval is not stopping the Set interval ? , Set interval keep on calling the function in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The below function is executed when the user press a button and video is in play event , below the
set interval is set , it will keep on calling the function for every 100 milli seconds.

```
video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  
    const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
    interval = setInterval(async () => {
      const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new                            faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
      const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
      canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
      faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
      console.log(interval,"Inside start")
    }, 100)
    // verify()
  })
```

Below function is for when the enters a stop button, i want the setinterval function to be stopped

```
stop.addEventListener('click',()=>
{
    clearInterval(interval)
    console.log(interval," stop is pressed " )
    localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
    video.src = '';
})
```

But , after the clear interval , the setinterval keep on calling its function , and iterval is being changed to some new value every time clear interval is called. Start is pressed only one time, when the stop is pressed ,new interval is assigned and start keep on running

[image]

if any want further info, kindly comment.

**update 1:**  when the stop button is clicked , setinterval is removed but the problem is the play event is triggered again and again. How can i stop the play event ?

```
stop.addEventListener('click',()=>
{
    debugger;
    clearInterval(interval)
    video.pause()
    console.log(interval," stop is pressed " )
    localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
    video.src = '';
})
```

video.pause() didnt work out

**update2:** i changed the logic without using the play event listener everything is working fine , in case is it possible to stop the play event triggering?

Comment: your code and log look fine, after pressing the stop the interval is cleared, the next log items contains another interval

Comment: there could another reason like the code triggers the play event again after the stop being clicked, but the interval looks fine, debug with breakpoints to see what happens

Comment: Could you  give any solution to stop the another interval you are referring ?

Comment: Try calling `clearInterval(interval)` at the start of your `play` callback. Otherwise if the `play` event happens more than once without stopping, the previous intervals will never be cleared.

Comment: Is your stop button nested inside the video? I'd guess the click event is bubbling up from the stop button to the video element. Try calling [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) inside your stop event to see if that resolves it.

Comment: @MarkHanna, stop button is not nested inside the video.so there is no bubbling up.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton, i tried it didnt workout, the main culprit here is play event is triggering again, after the stop is pressed.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev, Thank you giving the direction where the problem is occuring. How can i stop the triggering of play event?  tried video.pause() inside the stop event, but not working

Answer (score 0):

The `play` event is emitted when the value of `paused` attribute changes from `true` to `false`.

So you should probably be invoking `pause()` function on the video element to make sure that the event listener stops running.

[Edit] Since you mentioned video.pause() is not doing anything, and that we can see the interval id changing, could you please make the following change to the `play` event listener.

````
var interval;
video.addEventListener('play', () => {
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval= setInterval(your function, 100);
    ```
````

Comment: i tried it but the play event triggering again

Comment: Did you get any error when you called video.pause()? Did the video get paused, even though the listener was running?

Comment: i got no error, actually the video is a webcam stream , when the stop button is pressed i stopped the video track , so with or without the video.pause() the video will be stopped but the event listener is keep on running.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you please give that a shot

Comment: yes it will stop the previous interval, tbut he scenario is, play event is triggering again, then set Interval will also set new interval and loop continues

Comment: Saw your latest update. Is `autoplay` attribute enabled on the video? Also, please inspect the properties of the video during the various stages - `paused`, `playing` etc.
Is your code available on Github/codesandbox so we can get a better picture of what could be triggering it?